# Cannot find memory monitor in my android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

### This is how I want it to be.

[image: Android Studio 2.0 android monitor]

### This is how it is...also I checked Monitors section but it do not work.

[image: Android Studio 2.2.3 Android monitor]

I also searched Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration or Tools->Android->Android Monitor. First one did't do anything and second one is not available.

I am running Android Studio 2.2.3 on linux. I just cannot find Memory monitor in my android studio.

Edit: I did not checked Monitors tab correctly, and I found the Memory monitor section. Sorry for that. Also, is there a way to make my Android Monitor tab look like in the first image?

Comment: This on the screenshot is the memory monitor. What's the problem now?
(Btw: It looks different in my AS. I just have "monitors" tab. "Memory", "CPU" and "Network" is placed within this one "Monitor" view.) And you don't have any connected devices. What do you want to monitor then?

Comment: "This is how it is" -- you need to click on the "Monitors" tab. "also I checked Monitors section but it do not work" -- please explain, **in detail**, what "it do not work" means.

Comment: @Bevor Okay, my fault(really sorry), I found the memory monitor. Is there any way to resize it? Or make it look like the first image? Also, since I was a fool of not checking things correctly, should I delete this question?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, that was a mistake. Please check the edits.

Comment: "Is there any way to resize it?" -- it should be full-width, unless you have another tool window open on the bottom (in which case, minimize that tool). Height is adjustable by dragging the top edge. "is there a way to make my Android Monitor tab look like in the first image?" -- please explain **in detail** what you mean by this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am a beginner and I don't know these things. You solved my problem. I am happy of how it looks. Thanks. Also, since this question is not useful to anybody, should I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Monitor set of tabs are inside the Monitor tab, which itself is inside the Android Monitor tool. In your second screenshot, click the Monitor tab.

By default, this tool will take up the entire bottom edge of your IDE window. However, other tools docked on this edge will take up some of that space, if those tools are open (e.g., Gradle Console, Event Log). You can minimize those tools if desired, to give you more horizontal space. Or, drag the splitter between those tools to resize them.

Similarly, you can drag the top edge of the Android Monitor tool to change its height. While there is no splitter bar drawn in the UI, if you hover your mouse over the edge, you should see the mouse pointer turn into your platform-specific "resize" pointer image.